# Finding the Weyl group from a Cartan matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, weyl-group, cartan-geometry, semisimple-lie-algebras

I am looking to establish the relationship between Weyl groups and semisimple Lie algebras.  So far I have found the root space decomposition (I am using $\mathfrak{sl}(3, \mathbb{C}) $as my example).

From here, I have constructed a Cartan matrix.  I am now wondering where I go from here so that I can find the Weyl group from which the Lie algebra can be reconstructed.  Basically I am trying to find the generators for a Lie algebra.....but I am getting very confused.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finding the Weyl group from the Cartan matrix $M$ is quite simple. The actual generators are the simple reflections $s_i$, where
$$s_{i}(\alpha_j) = \alpha_j - M_{ij}\alpha_i$$
For the isomorphism class, you need to look at 
$$M_{ij}M_{ji}=4\cos^2\frac{\pi}{k_{ij}}$$
Then the generating relation is
$$(s_is_j)^{k_{ij}}=1$$
The isomorphism class is then determined by the Dynkin diagram. Knowing the isomorphism class gives you a better idea of what the roots are without having to work them out yourself. For $\mathfrak{sl}(3,\mathbb{C})$, one choice of positive roots is
$$t_i-t_j$$
for $1\leq i\lt j\leq 4$. Then the simple roots are $t_1-t_2$, $t_2-t_3$, and $t_3-t_4$. The reflections act as transpositions on the indices.

Comment: Thank you for your comment,it is helpful!  I haven't used anything to do with the isomorphism classes up until now so it is just that bit I am a little stuck with.  I know there are probably different ways to construct the Weyl group from the Lie algebra but I am wondering how the generators $\left\{   h_\alpha, e_\alpha, f_\alpha \right\} $and relations tie in with the Cartan matrix?  Sorry I am just getting a bit confused as to which order all the steps should be in from decomposing the semisimple Lie algebra to calculating its Weyl group?